# Ionic Thumbnail crop

Tags: ionic-framework, thumbnails

The original image is not quadratic. Currently my thumbnails are distorted. How can I create a cropped thumbnail? CSS Styles seems to have no effect.

```
<ion-thumbnail item-start style ="object-fit: cover;">
   <img src={{item.img}}>
</ion-thumbnail>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use the object fit at the img element.

`<ion-thumbnail item-start>
   <img class="fit-thumbnail" src="{{video.thumbnail}}" alt="">
</ion-thumbnail>`

`.fit-thumbnail { object-fit: cover; }`